# Set value=' '(empty String) where the field value is NULL (multiple columns)

Tags: mysql

I have a table contains lots of column. Many columns contain NULL value. But while I'm trying to create CSV file from it, NULL is being replaced by '/N'. I want to set all the columns value to empty string instead of NULL so that I don't have to face problem with '/N'

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: Maybe move the stool to the piano.

Comment: Is `/N` a typo for `\N`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FIELDS ESCAPED BY` clause along with `SELECT` query and specify an empty String or whitespace (`' '`) to get empty values instead of `\N`, e.g.:

```
SELECT * INTO file
FIELDS ESCAPED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM test_table;
```

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) MySQL's documentation about it, this is what it says:

> If the FIELDS ESCAPED BY character is empty, no characters are escaped
>   and NULL is output as NULL, not \N.

Answer (score 0):

You can update all the columns and set to empty string instead of NULL, If you don't want to continue with NULL.

If you want to continue with NULL in DB, then export into a temp DB table and apply above logic...

Answer (score 0):

First you need to update column default value with below query.

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `column_name` `column_name` varchar(length) default '';

UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name`='' where `column_name`='/N';
```

May this will help you.

Comment: `'/N'` matches the literal string `/N`, not `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use resultset metadata. Iterate through all the columns and check for null values.

```
ResultSet rsMain = stmt.executeQuery(selectQuery);
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rsMain.getMetaData();
while(rsMain.next()){
for (int i = 1; i <=rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
if(rsMain.wasNull())
     {
        sb.append('');// this is the string buffer that writes to the csv
        sb.append(',');
      }
 }
  }
```

Comment: What language is this? The question is tagged `mysql`.

Comment: I assumed he is using java to create csv files. How are you creating CSV files? @khairul alam

Comment: It seems he's using MySQL's `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` to create a CSV file directly from MySQL. When it puts null values into the output file it escapes them as `\N` (which he mistyped as `/N` in the question).

Comment: Ohh sorry, My bad @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

You can update the table like this:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET col1 = IFNULL(col1, ''),
    col2 = IFNULL(col2, ''),
    col3 = IFNULL(col3, ''),
    ...
```

Once you've done this, you should probably change the schema so that nulls aren't allowed and the default value is `''`, so you don't have to go through this again.